# Why is poizone's sound altered in Fl studio after saving?

Tags: sound, post-production, plug-ins, fl-studio, song

I use [poizone](http://www.image-line.com/plugins/Synths/Poizone/) plugin in my song.
My problem is that when I play song in FL studio it sounds amazing, but after saving song in my computer it changes only the poizone's sound..
In FL studio the sound is wobbly and high, but after save it goes low note and straight one ton without wobble...

I've tried saving in all formats (wav, mp3 and ogg)

for wav it's 512 bitrate and 32 bits, and once I've tried 64 bitrate and 16 bits

for mp3 I've tried 512 and 450 bitrate, and 512 and 320 bitrate

for ogg I've tried 512 and 450 bitrate

Comment: By saving do you mean rendering?

Comment: It might be a product of using an FL Studio demo? I haven't used PoiZone in forever so I don't remember.

Comment: @johnatan Yupp rendering

Comment: @timaeus222 yupp i found out it was problem that i had trial and poizone must be paid so it can render

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you bought Poizone or does it come with your version of FL Studio right out of the box?  Perhaps you are in trial mode.  It should say on the plugin.

Comment: Yup thank you very much, it was problem that poizone should be paid and i had trial, so it can not be rendered if it is in trial... Thanks